# How do I fix fix getting "None" as a response when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to create a small code that gets the views from a youtube video and prints them. However using this code when printing the text var I just get the response "None". Is there a way to get a response of the actual view count using these libraries?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find('span', {'class': "view-count style-scopeytd-video-view-count-renderer"})

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why, you should use `wget` or `curl` to fetch a copy of that page and look at it, or use "view source" from your browser.  That's what `requests` sees.  None of those classes appear in the HTML you get back.  That's why you get `None` -- because there ARE none.

YouTube builds all of its pages dynamically, through Javascript.  `requests` doesn't interpret Javascript.  If you need to do this, you'll need to use something like Selenium to run a real browser with a Javascript interpreter built in.